# Axle nut sizes on a 2001 Honda Shadow

Tags: honda, motorcycle, axle

It seems that the axle nut on a 2001 Honda Shadow are different sizes on either side of the bike.  What size are these so I may get the correct wrench to work with them.  I have tried other sources and I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Axle nut is 27mm and the other side is hex head 24mm, this was on a 2002 - it should be the same from 2000 to 2007.

Confirmed axle nut size on friends 2001.